# how to make a straight line of floating elements go overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

I currently have a "straight" line of differently positioned items floating: left - and going from the outer left of the  taking up all space to the outer right of the body.

My issue right now is that ive added more items than can fit in the 100% body "container" so the floating items will naturally break down a line.

What im looking to do achieve though is, that I would just want my items keep going into some overflow:hidden state (and not break down)- so that I basically could keep on adding items without breaking down the line.

My HTML is basically the following - [the issue can also be seen here](http://devsgs.com/preview/mm/):

```
#lights {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
overflow: hidden;
}

.lightItem {
    float: left;
}

// ** I basically repeat this pattern in the straight line  // *
.lightItem.c1Light_1 {
    padding: 38px 0 0 42px;
}

.lightItem.c1Light_2 {
    padding: 37px 0 0 82px;
}

.lightItem.c1Light_3 {
    padding: 46px 0 0 59px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `overflow:hidden`  and a height to `#lights`. So your css for `#lights` would be:

```
#lights {
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
overflow: hidden;
height: 78px; //set this to whatever you need
}
```

Comment: oh darn, tried all kind of things out, but for some reason didnt try to add any height, hehe. Thanks a bunch man, that solved the issue very easy!

Comment: @user1231561 Glad to help! Just a note about the height, it's set to 78px as that is the tallest height you have on those images. The overflow:hidden then clips anything that exceeds that 78px height.

Answer (score 0):

Well one trick would be wrap it into a div with a different (wider) width and let the line element hide the overflow you can adjust it based on your needs it a really simple example ofc and since i'm quite lazy i didn't try it out on all browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #main_wrapper
        {
            width: 960px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: auto;
        }

        #main_wrapper .overflow_line
        {
            width: 300%;
            height: 200px;
            clear: both;
            border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        }

        #main_wrapper .overflow_line > div
        {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 120px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_wrapper">
        <div class="overflow_line">
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Shadowdroid,

Thanks so much for taking the time to illustrate with an example - your answer with the width 300% approach would actually also solve my issue, so thanks for setting my mind in the right direction! :)